# Get max available browser height without browser toolbar- javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have a problem, I have container populated with header, main and footer. On the front page for example for desktop users header should be 12% of available browser height and main should be 88%(without the browser toolbar and windows/android/ios/linux bars), footer should be only visible when user scroll the page.

I considered these solutions:

```
header {
    height: 12vh;
}

main { 
    height: 88vh;
}
```

but header and main shouldn't resize when user resize browser height.

```
let root = document.documentElement;

root.style.setProperty("--deviceHeight",
    window.screen.availHeight - (window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight) + "px");
```

but when user change browser height and refresh the page - --deviceHeight is calculated once more.

I tried also:

```
root.style.setProperty("--deviceHeight", window.screen.availHeight)
```

but then output is different for chrome, opera and other browsers.

To conclude - I want to get max available height without windows and browser bars and resize header and main to that height, so then header height + main height would be 100% of max available browser (inner?) height, but when user resize browser on desktop -> header and main height shouldn't change.

Is this possible in css without multiple media queries? If not, is this possible in javascript / js + jquery? 
Or mayble should I use multiple jquery (for example iteration by 10 in media queries)

```
:root {
    --deviceHeight: 299px
}
@media only screen and (min-width 300px) {
    :root {
      --deviceHeight = 300px
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 301px) {
    :root {
        --deviceHeight = 302px;
    }
}
etc.
```

I'm looking for best solution for front end programming and SEO, any advise, even if complicated, will be great!

Comment: I might be wrong, but if you just use 'height: 100%', isn't that how tall the browser is? E.g: If you put that in the css for a div it should stretch to fill the viewport.

Comment: You're using relative units, if you don't want values to change use fixed units.

Comment: @TorNato if I for example use height 12% and body and html will be 100vh or 100% i will still get header of 12% height od viewport, not actual max available height od browser, i tried that.

Comment: @Zohir Salak  I know I use relative units, I don't want to use fixed units because then I have to define hundreds or thousands media queries in CSS with fixed value, I want to find the best solution for SEO and performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said that the header's size shouldn't change when browser's height is changing , so you can use a fixed unit and calculate the rest for your mainf content :

```
header {
    height: 300px; // for exemple
}

main { 
    height: calc( 100vh - 300px ); // calculate the available space
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but neither main height should change. I found a closest solution to my need, comment below ;)

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution, not necessary what i wanted, but it is closest to what i desired.

```
header {
    height: 160px;
}

@media only screen and (max-height: 599px) {
    main {
        height: calc(599px - 160px);
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-height: 600px) {
    main {
        height: calc(100vh - 160px);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending to the topic I wanted also point out this:

get full height without toolbar:
`window.outerHeight`
which results in:
[image: window.outerWidth and window.outerHeight]

Check out [dmitripavlutin](https://dmitripavlutin.com/screen-window-page-sizes/) for a nice graphical illustration of the window attributes

Depending on your needs you can adapt to window inner sizes, outer sizes, screen available sizes and so on.

Browser compability regarding to [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/outerWidth):
[image]

I wanted to mention this here, because sometimes I feel like a complete noob and would be happy to find this input at first glance instead of wasting time creating complex mathematical solutions calculating these things^^